# Clustered Column Chart bars get squashed when more than one year of data monthly data is included

Tags: powerbi

When I have more than one year of monthly data in my Clustered Column chart my data bars get squashed and separated with the x axis type set to Continuous. Setting the x axis type to Categorical fixes the problem but I lose the Trend Line. The Trend Line is a must-have requirement from the end user so I can't leave it out.[Desired Result but I need a Trend Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jPxL.png)

[This is what happens with the x axis set to Continuous:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpPwR.png)

When I reduce the amount of data to 12 months everything is ok - bars look good and I have a trend line - surely I should be able to display more that one year's worth of data?

[This is what I want but I want to display more than one year's worth of monthly data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fENG8.png)

Comment: Seems to me you are not working with dates but numbers. You need to convert the numbers 201801 to a real date.

Comment: Thanks Aldert. I'll give that a try. Regards, mmmg

Answer (score 0):

your suggestion seemed to work for the most part but my Month Year labels aren't lining up with the correct columns. For instance Jul 2019 should be directly under the right-most columns. Also, how can I get Month Year labels under every column not just every few.
[Note that the Month Year labels seem to be shifted one column to the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FCM36.png)

Comment: When you hoover over the column, does the tooltip show the correct month? If this is also incorrect, you might have a mistake in your conversion..

Comment: Hi Aldert, thanks for your response. When I hover over the column the correct Month Year is displayed. Regards, mmmg

Comment: Can you turn on your gridlines of the visual to see how it lines up?

Comment: Hi Aldert, thanks again for your continued help. I turned on the vertical gridlines but this made no difference.

Comment: Hi Aldert, they are, but that doesn't line up with the clustered column that is the data for that Month. The annoying thing is that when I change the 'Type' of the x-axis from 'Continuous' to 'Categorical' it looks fine but I lose my Trend Line and the end user won't budge on the Trend Line being a mandatory requirement. Thanks for your continued help Aldert.